# Marketing Cloud SmartCapture javascript validation

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, smart-capture

I am trying to add field validation with Javascript on a SmartCapture form. The field validation is working, however I get POST 500 (Internal Server Error). For some reason, the post method breaks when I add the validation.

Here below is the code (only the parts relevant to this issue). Can you please help? Thanks!

```
<form id="smartcapture-block-avp824vcmv6" class="smartcapture-content-wrapper fuelux" onsubmit="return validateDate()">

<script type="text/javascript"> 

var today = new Date();
today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);


console.log ("Current date is: " + today);
   function validateDate() 
   { 
   var fday=document.getElementsByClassName("select day")[0].value;
     console.log("fday is: "+fday);
   var fmonth=document.getElementsByClassName("select month")[0].value; 
   var fyear=document.getElementsByClassName("select year")[0].value; 
     var inputDate = fday + "/" + fmonth + "/" + fyear;
     var inputDate = new Date(inputDate);
     console.log(inputDate);

   submitOK="true"; 

     if (inputDate <= today) 
   {  
     console.log("input date earlier than today");
   var Valert = "Date should not be earlier than today \n"; 
   submitOK="false"; 
   }  
   else 
   { 
     console.log("input date later than today");
   var Valert = ""; 
   } 
     if (submitOK=="false") 
   { 
   alert(Valert); 
   return false; 
   } 

   }

   </script>
```